# vue.js 2 how to properly nest components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Can you please tell me how to properly add components to other components?
The example below does not work. The child component is not displayed inside the parent.

```
<div id="app">
    <parent>
        <child></child>
    </parent>
</div>

<template id='child'>
    <div>child component</div>
</template>

<template id='parent'>
    <div>parent component</div>
</template>

<script>

    var child = {
        template: '#child',
        data: function () {
            return {}
        }
    };

    var parent = {
        template: '#parent',
        data: function () {
            return {}
        }
    };

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
            'parent': parent,
            'child': child
        }
    })
</script>
```

sample: https://jsfiddle.net/05gc05sk/1/

how to properly nest components?

Comment: Did you try [reading the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does work.

Only add `<slot>` ([Content Distribution with Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots)) to your parent component.

```
<template id='parent'>
  <div>
    parent component
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```